# XBMC unable to connect via SFTP to server

Tags: ssh, sftp, kodi

I have a raspberry pi xbmc server set up at home that I use to stream videos over my local network, but I'd like to be able to stream videos over the internet. I am able to SSH and SFTP into my raspberry pi using the terminal and I can download anything from there at ~700KB/s, I figure that's a good enough speed to allow streaming. However, for some reason when I use SFTP and the same credentials/port to try to add the device to my XBMC player, XBMC refuses to connect and displays the message: "XBMC was unable to connect to the network location. This could be due to the network not being connected. Would you like to add it anyway?"

There's likely an easy solution that I'm overlooking, but I can't think of anything that I haven't already tried. I can provide additional information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well you didn't mention that you port forwarded the SFTP port but one could assume that when your terminaling in you are doing so remotely and so the ports must be forwarded.

Other than that, SFTP and SSH by default use the same port IIRC (22) so you may want to set at least one of those to a non-default port so the servers aren't overlapping.

Also depending on what machine Kodi is running on, you could map the SFTP share to a drive and then add that in Kodi to side-step any Kodi related issues. ([SFTP Net Drive](https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/download-release.php))

Alternatively, you could switch to another remote share like [SSHFS](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/) or WebDAV (HTTPS).

Comment: I've since switched to using sshfs instead of using xbmc at all and it is working much better.